No route found for "GET http://localhost/drupals_new_test/web/"
Once I create a new database, and import all data from the old one, update my settings and restore the folders and files, I get this error:
No route found for "GET http://localhost/drupals_new_test/web/"
How to connect old database in drupal 10
$databases = array (
  'default' =>
  array (
    'default' =>
    array (
      'database' => 'lobo',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);

how to solve this

Did you tried remove one of the “default” keys?


drush ev '\Drupal::service("router.builder")->rebuild();'

By rebuilding the routes and clearing all caches, you are addressing the core issue that typically causes the "No route found" error in Drupal. This step ensures that Drupal’s routing system is aware of all paths and can resolve them correctly. If this step does not resolve the issue, then proceed to verify the database connection and ensure that all dependencies and configurations are correct.
